# Disable wheel scrolling on main window

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I can't seem to find an answer to this, my apologizes if it has already been answered.

I'm using the scroll feature in a div in my website, and what happens is that after the user wheel-scrolls down to the bottom of the div, it automatically keeps scrolling the main page. I want to make it so that if the pointer is inside the div, to stop and only if the pointer leaves the div zone, only then should the whole site scroll. Any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To disable the `wheel` event, use `e.preventDefault()` like so :

```
$('#myDiv').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;

    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }
    else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eXQf3/371/